# Why is the LineRenderer displaying on lowest layer on Android but not in Editor?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, canvas, line

I have a 2D app with many canvases that have UI components. The canvases are displayed using SortingOrder for various functionality. At some point, I enable the signature canvas with a linerenderer.

On Android, the linerenderer always renders on the bottom layer so I cannot see the signature.
Yet, on the Editor, it works properly and displays on top where I can see the signature.

I have been playing around with layers, sorting orders but cannot make it work on Android on the top layer.

BTW: I'm pretty sure its not a shader problem ([Line renderer is not working for android build game](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28177705/line-renderer-is-not-working-for-android-build-game)) because when I disable all canvases but the signature one and publish to Android it works fine.

---!!!! So I tested my App on Android Version 7.1.1 and it works as expected. It does the problem above on Android Version 9.
Any ideas??

Answer (score 0):

I think if I upgrade the Unity version to the latest it will solve the problem. I am using Unity 2019.1 - I attempt to upgrade App to 2020.